# How can an Objective-C Class be tested to determine if it responds to a static selector (a class method)?

Tags: objective-c

This is most easily explained with a brief example. Let's say I have the following protocol and class definitions:

```
@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject>
@optional
+ (BOOL)methodA;
@end

@interface ClassA : NSObject <ProtocolA>
@end
```

`ClassA` may or may not define `methodA`. If I was working with an instance of `ClassA` and an instance method, I could test the instance with `respondsToSelector:`. In this situation, however, I cannot think of any clean way to determine if `ClassA` defines (responds to) `methodA`.

**EDIT:**
I was silly and did not make my example specific enough, which meant the answer to the question was not exactly the solution to my problem -- so I am including a bit more code and the warning I am getting:

```
Class <ProtocolA> classRef = [ClassA class];

if([classRef respondsToSelector:@selector(methodA)]) {}
```

The above code throws the following warning:
" Instance method '`respondsToSelector:`' found instead of class method '`respondsToSelector:`'"

I only just now noticed that if I explicitly cast `classRef` to `(Class)` then the warning goes away. I still find that odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[instance class] respondsToSelector:@selector(methodA)]`

Every instance of a class has a pointer to it's class object which can be retrieved by calling `class`. This object (classes are objects in Objective C) can be probed with `respondsToSelector:` just like any other object.

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right, but I realized my question was not quite getting at the problem I am having. Do you mind taking a look and seeing if you can explain the warning I am getting that seemingly should not be there?

Comment: That seems very strange to me, because you are declaring it as a class one line up! It's not just you either, I tried it myself and get the same warning. I found that if I take off the <ProtocolA> on the first line, the warning goes away. I wonder if this is a compiler bug?

Comment: Well, ultimately inconsequential now that I know it works and is supposed to work that way. Thanks!